# z3opt python -- minimizing square

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I was considering using z3 to minimize problems involving squares. But when I write this simple example (z3opt in python 3) :

```
from z3 import *

a = Real('a')
b = Real('b')

cost = Real('cost')

opt = Optimize()
opt.add(a + b == 3)
opt.add(And(a >= 0, a <= 10))
opt.add(And(b >= 0, b <= 10))
opt.add(cost == a * 10.0 + b ** 2.0)
h = opt.minimize(cost)
print(opt.check())
print(opt.reason_unknown())
print(opt.lower(h))
print(opt.model())
```

The check returns "unknown":

```
unknown
(incomplete (theory arithmetic))
-1*oo
[b = 0, cost = 30, a = 3]
```

Am I defining the problem in the wrong way or is this an intrinsic limitation of z3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [νZ - An Optimizing SMT Solver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-nuz.pdf) and [νZ - Maximal Satisfaction with Z3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-scss2014.pdf) explicitly mention that **Linear Arithmetic Optimization** is supported, whereas you are trying to optimise a *non-linear objective*.

I guess the authors would mention it if *non-linear objectives* were supported, since it is not a minor feature.

---

**Workaround.** In your example you can obviously use a workaround to get past this issue since *cost* is given by the sum of two *positive and independent addends*, e.g. turn the problem into a lexicographic optimization problem in which you first minimize `a` and then `b`:

```
(declare-fun a () Real)
(declare-fun b () Real)
(declare-fun cost () Real)
(assert (= (+ a b) 3))
(assert (<= 0 a))
(assert (<= a 10))
(assert (<= 0 b))
(assert (<= b 10))
(assert (= cost (+ (* 10 a) (* b b))))
(minimize a)
(minimize b)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and get

```
sat
(objectives
 (a 0)
 (b 3)
)
(model 
  (define-fun b () Real
    3.0)
  (define-fun cost () Real
    9.0)
  (define-fun a () Real
    0.0)
)
```

But I guess this is a *minimal example* for a larger problem, thus it might not be of much help.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion as to an alternative to z3 that could solve this? I was using it for its convenient interface (automatically building large systems of equations, of which most are linear) but find that I cannot get around this problem.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I don't know of any *SMT* solver that provides direct optimization procedures of *non-linear objectives* at the present time. I regret to say that my knowledge in related fields is not deep enough to suggest you some other tool to solve this problem. @GeromePistre